# Express route regex exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, routes

i know this is probably a silly question but I cant make it work, Im trying got match any route that does not match a word, api for example (exclude /api/*) but I cant make it work:

```
'/^(?=\/).(?!api\/).*$'
```

That doesn't work, then I tried this site: http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/ just to test I match / and give me this code:

```
/^\/?$/i
```

Then I tried at express but it didn't match /

```
Cannot GET /
```

Then I'm guessing theres something wrong with the code and not with the regex, do you have some hint?

```
app.get('/^\/?$/i', function(req, res) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex here doesn't seem like the right approach, it seems more like you'd want to use a parameterized route to handle protected routes.

```
app.get('/:directory/:page', function(req, res, next){
  if(req.params.directory.toLowerCase() == 'api') res.redirect('/') //or whatever you want it to do
  else {
    //whatever your default action is
  }
}
```

If you wanted to exclude several and handle them in the same way, you could make your `if` statement use regex:

```
if(/^(api|other_directory|whatever_else)$/i.test(req.params.directory)) res.redirect('/')
```